# Ordinary differential eqaution: motion in straight line

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If the acceleration of a particle moving along a straight line is defined as a=C/v ,
where:
a=acceleration of particle;
C=constant;
v=velocity of particle;

and v=0 at t=0

What is the velocity of the particle as a function of time t?

Comment: $$a(t) = \dfrac{dv}{dt}$$ can you take it from there?

Comment: not really, can you expand a bit more please, thanks

Comment: Let's take my comment a bit further
$$
a(t) = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{C}{v}\tag{*}
$$
Now we have separable differential equation. Have you been taught how to solve equations of the form (*)